# Поиск по ячейкам датафрейма Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, поиск

Люди добрые, помогите пожалуйста, хотя бы идеей, а то перепробовал все из мануалов, и не получается

Имеется датафрейм, в котором ячейки заполнены сложными цифровыми и буквенными данными.
Необходимо извлечь по шаблону (например, \d{3,10}) последовательно из каждой ячейки список чисел и добавить их в новый датафрейм (или список), при этом желательно сохранить привязку к конкретной ячейке (номер ячейки + номер строки). Просто регулярные выражения почему-то не могу заставить работать в датафрейме.

Буду очень признателен любому совету.

UPD:

датафрейм примерно такой

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"number":[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                 "products 1": ["3650482     Чай  3495758 3379939 3482097 3373028 3375442 3373024", 
                                "4001101 Приправа 4001098 4001095 4001093 4001097 4001100", 
                                "3428416 Фундук", 
                                " " ], 
                 "products 2": ["4106381 Напиток 4106382 4106380", 
                                "4090345 Шоколад  4090347", 
                                " ", 
                                "108609 Майонез"], 
                 "products 3": ["3273901 Соус соевый 3379232 ", 
                                " ", 
                                "4045462 Огурцы", 
                                "12334 Апельсины"]})
```

Необходимо извлечь из столбцов products 1, products 2, products 3, только цифры артикулов, которых может и не быть в ячейке, а может и быть 5-8 шт.

```
получить:
№ Artikul Row        Line
1 3650482 products1  1
2 4001097 products1  2
3 4001100 products1  2
4 12334   products3  4
......
```

Comment: Приведите пример исходных данных и пример желаемого результата. Тогда у вашего вопроса есть шанс получить ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так попробовать

```
def numeric_split(x):
    return [i for i in x.split() if i.isnumeric()]
# Берем только цифры из строки    

cols = ['products1', 'products2', 'products3']

# применяем к нашим столбцам

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(numeric_split)
df.index = df.index + 1 # чтобы нумерация столбца Line была не с 0, а с 1
new_df = df[cols].stack().explode().dropna().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'Line', 'level_1': 'Row',
                                                                     0: 'Article'})
>>> print(new_df)

  Line        Row    Article
0      1  products1  3650482
1      1  products1  3495758
2      1  products1  3379939
3      1  products1  3482097
4      1  products1  3373028
5      1  products1  3375442
6      1  products1  3373024
.....
```

Comment: спасибо, дорогой человек!

Comment: *Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.*

Comment: Все наконец получилось, но немного бы по-другому хотел. Можно ли искать в строке с помощью регулярного выражения числа или хотя бы ограничить количество цифр в числе больше 4 (от 1000 и более), иначе он собирает много мусорных значений

Comment: можно. если у вас числа строкового типа, через *str.contains* и *str.extract* в pandas, там можно использовать регулярки. [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) и [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Можно ли искать в строке с помощью регулярного выражения числа или хотя бы ограничить количество цифр в числе больше 4 (от 1000 и более)

попробуйте примерно такой код (в примере числа ограничены 7 символами):

```
rows = [r.str.extractall('(?P<Article>\d{7,})').assign(Line=i) for i,r in df.set_index('number').iterrows()]
res = pd.concat(rows).droplevel(-1).rename_axis('Row').reset_index()

print(res)
'''
           Row  Article  Line
0   products 1  3650482     1
1   products 1  3495758     1
2   products 1  3379939     1
3   products 1  3482097     1
4   products 1  3373028     1
5   products 1  3375442     1
6   products 1  3373024     1
7   products 2  4106381     1
8   products 2  4106382     1
9   products 2  4106380     1
10  products 3  3273901     1
11  products 3  3379232     1
12  products 1  4001101     2
13  products 1  4001098     2
14  products 1  4001095     2
15  products 1  4001093     2
16  products 1  4001097     2
17  products 1  4001100     2
18  products 2  4090345     2
19  products 2  4090347     2
20  products 1  3428416     3
21  products 3  4045462     3
```